# How to combine elements in 2D array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array that looks like this:

```
var colors = [["red", "blue"], ["green", "black"], ["orange", "purple"]];
```

How can I run a simple method to combine the elements in each array, like this:

```
[["red blue"], ["green black"], ["orange purple"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const merged = colors.map(([first, second]) => `${first} ${second}`)
```

Also you can deconstruct these params and join them using templates.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this via [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const colors = [["red", "blue"], ["green", "black"], ["orange", "purple"]];

const merged = colors.map(x => [x.join(' ')]);

console.log(merged);
```

It seems odd that you'd want the merged items to each be an array containing a single item but that's what you asked for. If you wanted an array of strings instead, you'd just remove the square brackets from around the `join` call:

```js
 const merged = colors.map(x => x.join(' '));

 // ["red blue", "green black", "orange purple"]
```